# ¿Qué palabra puede utilizarse con una connotación intermedia entre hostigar y molestar?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

Según Google hostigar significa: [Hostigar significado Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=hostigar%20significado&ei=Wn0RYtmuEezW5OUP3tuyqAY&ved=0ahUKEwjZw-v39Yz2AhVsK7kGHd6tDGUQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=hostigar%20significado&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyDQgAEIAEELEDEEYQ-QEyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46CQgAEEMQRhD5AToLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6CAguELEDEIMBOggIABCABBCxAzoLCC4QsQMQxwEQowI6EQguEIAEELEDEMcBENEDENQCOgQIABBDOgoIABCxAxCDARBDOgsILhCABBDHARCvAToOCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQrwE6BwgAELEDEEM6CwguEIAEEMcBENEDOgQILhBDOgcIABCABBAKOgUIABDEAkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFCYA1joFmCsGGgWcAB4AYABkgKIAYkDkgEFMC4xLjGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)

> Acosar con insistencia a una persona o animal, persiguiéndolo,
> molestándolo, golpeándolo, etc.

Por lo general se usa cuando una persona le hace a otra la vida imposible. Pero hay situaciones intermedias entre una simple molestia temporal a la que se llamaría "molestar", del tipo "me molestó lo que dijo una vez", en contraposición con acoso u hostigamiento, más cuando estas 2 últimas en muchos países tienen consecuencias penales, en donde usar la palabra hostigamiento sería desde una exageración hasta una mentira. Por ejemplo, cuando alguien no te hace la vida imposible pero de tanto en tanto te molesta.

¿Qué palabra puede utilizarse para una situación intermedia o con una connotación intermedia entre hostigar y molestar?

Comment: "Fastidiar" cabe en ese grado intermedio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Atosigar

> Inquietar, acuciar con exigencias o preocupaciones.

### Incordiar

> tr. coloq. Molestar, importunar

### Martirizar

> Molestar o incomodar a alguien de forma intensa y reiterada.

Comment: Incordiar me parece buena. De hecho dice que uno de sus sinónimos es fastidiar, que era una de las palabras que se me ocurrió después de hacer las pregunta. Veremos si hay más respuestas

Comment: incordiar: 
Fastidiar o molestar a una persona con algo que resulta pesado o repetitivo.
"paseando por el parque no dejaron de incordiarnos los vendedores ambulantes"

Answer (score 1):

Hostigar, hostigamiento me suena a mí como acoso sexual, psicológico (como para inducir a que la víctima haga algo), legal o cuando alguien quiere imponer su pensamiento a la fuerza.

Para expresar que una persona le hace a otra la vida imposible, entonces diría algo como: torturar sistemáticamente, quebrar, maltratar, alterar, hartar.

Si buscas algo intermedio como de algo más suave: incomodar, molestar, agotar, agobiar, fastidiar, irritar, joder. Odiosear ni cargosear lo he escuchado, pero sí como adjetivo, ser odioso o cargante.

> cargosear
> (v.) Arg. irritar, importunar, fastidiar, molestar

> cargosear.
> (kaɾγoθe'aɾ) verbo transitivo. molestar de manera reiterada a alguien

> huevear 1. tr. vulg. Chile. molestar (causar fastidio).

> agobiar 5. tr. desus. Rebajar, humillar, confundir.

> odiosear tr. Chile y Perú. Fastidiar, cansar, aburrir.

> joder intr. Chile, Argentina y México. Causar molestia o fastidiar en alto grado y con frecuencia en forma mal intencionada

> joder
> joder. ...// Joder la cachimba o joder la pita. loe. vulg. molestar, fregar.

Algo más rebuscado: importunar.

> majaderear, tr. Chile, Antillas, Colombia, Perú y Venezuela. Importunar.
> molestar.

"No seas majadero", pero majaderear no lo he escuchado.

Algo más coloquial y reiterativo: mosquear. (como enervar adj. enervante)

> mosquear
> COLOQUIAL•ESPAÑA
> Hacer [algo que se dice o hace] que una persona se sienta enfadada u ofendida.
> "tantas tonterías acabarán por mosquearlo y cuando no está de buen humor se pone insoportable"

> mosquear 1. v. tr., intr. y prnl. coloquial Causar enfado en una persona

Comment: Entre hostigar y maltratar, quebrar etc no le veo la diferencia. De hecho uno de los significados de hostigar es dar golpes, por lo que también incluye maltrato físico, bullying, etc. Creo que tienes una idea de hostigar más leve de lo que realmente es. Agobiar es una buena palabra como respuesta de la pregunta

Comment: En México y Guatemala también se usa el verbo *chingar*, el cual es tantito más pesado que *joder*.

Comment: @Pablo Sí, hostigar me suena más técnico, incluso con disturb entiendo el concepto, pero no diría "a está inquietando a b".  Atosigar sí, pero no siempre en un sentido negativo. Incordiar no se dice por acá. Mosquear lo decía un latinoamericano que vivió en españa y me parece de lo más normal, pero eso es algo personal.

Comment: Se me olvidó *fregar*.

Answer (score 0):

No se puede decir que exista estrictamente un término intermedio entre Hostigar y Molestar, son aspectos diferentes.

Siempre dependerá del lugar, el contexto en que se enuncie la palabra y de la confianza que se tiene con el interlocutor. Así este aspecto queda sometido a esas variables y cada hablante en función de estos parámetros *empleará* unos sinónimos u otros.
Ejemplos;

- Si hay confianza nosotros decimos "no te pases" - la otra persona entiende que esta molestando o ha dicho algo que ha sido considerado como ofensivo. Si utiliza la palabra majadero esta indicando cierta confianza e indica a su interlocutor que esta haciendo tonterías y por tanto, que no diga ó haga más el tonto.
- Si no hay confianza, pero se desea ser grosero decimos "¡no me jodas!" - esta indicando a la otra persona que se vaya y no busque problemas.
- Si se utiliza el lenguaje escrito perfectamente puede indicarlo con los verbos incomodar ó importunar.

Por ejemplo, *cuando alguien no te hace la vida imposible pero de tanto en tanto te molesta*. se puede utilizar la forma coloquial, pues se presupone que ya se posee cierta confianza con esa persona, se inicia con "ya esta aquí el pesado/a de siempre" y se sigue con "No me des más guerra" ó "No me des más la guerra" ó  - esta indicando que esa persona de vez en cuando vuelve a ciertos temas o comportamientos parecidos utilizando los mismos modos que en otras viejas batallas que pare ya.

- Otra más formal e igualmente plausible es "no seas cansino/a" - indica a la persona que esta molestando y que ya ha molestado en otras ocasiones, por eso cansa esa molestia periódica, sube el grado de molestar por repetición.

En general dependerá del contexto.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Diego

Comment: Por acá no necesariamente tiene que haber confianza para decir: "Nos seas majadero" e incluso se puede decir sin tutear: "No sea majadero" para descalificar.